# Unregister for push notifications in iOS 8

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to send remote push notifications to logged in users only. I must be 100% sure, that no push notification will be send, if user is logged out (sensitive data - banking application).

Possible solution is send logout request to my server, but it's not guaranteed, that request will be delivered to the server and is not good to say to user: "Sorry, an error is occurred, you have not been logged out.".

I find in Apple documentation method `unregisterForRemoteNotifications()`, but I don't know if is a good idea call it in logout action.

Comment: Just don't send confidential details via push, send an identifier and load the confidential details only in the app

Comment: Problem is, that if another user log in, notifications from previous user will be sent to him. So actual user can see badges for previous user but after he opens the app, nothing will be there. I must ensure unregistering for push notifications.

Comment: So call it on login of the username doesn't match

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may call that method during logout, but documentation also mention that

> You should call this method in rare circumstances only

So it would be better to ensure that your request was successfully delivered to server, then logout user from your app. Also, as said above, and noticed in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

> You should not include customer information (or any sensitive data) as custom payload data

Comment: This is dilemma, it's not user friendly if user logout depends on request success. Apps like Swarm can logout you immediately and no push notifications are coming after that.

Comment: @Deny you also may send your logout request in background without blocking UI, but in that case you should handle failures and recreate logout requests. If data in your app is sensitive enough, users will wait for total logout, as at web versions of banking systems, not only leaving site by just closing tab in the browser